# How does javascript engine know when network request is complete?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise, event-loop

I understand the concept of promises, an asynchronous task is resolved with `resolve` function after it's complete.
Classic example would be:

```
const futureValue = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("some value... tutorials pretend there's an API response here")
    }, 1000)
})
```

After, it can be used like so:

```
futureValue.then(r => { 
    // ... do stuff with the response 
})
```

or in an asynchronous function:

```
async () => {
    const response = await futureValue
    // ... do stuff with the response
}
```

My question is, given that Javascript knows which tasks are asynchronous and need to be placed on an event loop, how does the event loop know when the tasks that are outside of its control finished?

To be more clear, in case of `setTimeout`, Javascript is the one doing the counting for `setTimeout`, so naturally it knows when it is finished and resolves the `Promise` itself. I'm confused about the inner mechanism when it comes to network requests. How does it know when the response from the server arrived? is it just asking "are you there?" over and over again until the response is "yes" and then resolves to that response? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: promises are queued in a microtask queue, which is checked on every tick. I'd suggest watch this video for very clear understanding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: "javascript is the one doing the counting for setTimeout" nope, JS is not the responsible for timers, "How does javascript engine know when network request is complete?", it doesn't, the JS engine has no idea of what a network request is. Remember, browsers are not written in JS, JS is executed as part of the browser environment in various places, notabily in few steps of the event loop (which itslef is in no way powered by JS either) but it is not the core of the browser. You could very well have a compliant web browser without a JS engine.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I'm treating Javascript as a browser language and ignore its possible server-side uses.

The event loop might check for the `setTimeout`/`setInterval` condition, depending on the implementation (every browser implements Javascript separately and these implementations might differ greatly for multiple features, including this one), but the request's response is a browser event, that ultimately covers a network event under the hood. Javascript kindly asks the browser to send a request out and asks to be notified. The browser, on its turn, issues a network event and kindly asks the operating system to send it out and once that is completed, it handles the request completion in its own way.

If I were to implement Javascript for a browser, then the browser would push the response to a queue and Javascript's event loop would check for that queue in its event loop. If empty, do nothing. If some event(s) are in there, then it would pop it and process it, ultimately reaching to your callbacks.